# This code is working on my local machine but not in google colab. Can anyone please give me a solution

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the entire code ,this scrapes product details lke name price and link from an e-commerce website and displays the output and gives a csv file as well as displays graph.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def get_data():

    global items
    while True:
        search = input("What product do you want to search for?(Type '0' to quit) \n")
        if search == '0':
            break
        else:
            url = f"https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d={search}&N=4131"
            page = requests.get(url).text
            doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
            page_text = doc.find(class_="list-tool-pagination-text").strong
            pages = int(str(page_text).split("/")[-2].split(">")[-1][:-1])
            items_found = {}

            for page in range(1, pages + 1):
                url = f"https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d={search}&N=4131&page={page}"
                page = requests.get(url).text
                doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
                try:
                    div = doc.find(class_="item-cells-wrap border-cells items-grid-view four-cells expulsion-one-cell")
                    items = div.find_all(text=re.compile(search))
                except Exception:
                    print('Product not found')

                for item in items:
                    parent = item.parent
                    if parent.name != "a":
                        continue
                    link = parent['href']
                    next_parent = item.find_parent(class_="item-container")
                    try:
                        price = next_parent.find(class_="price-current").find("strong").string
                        items_found[item] = {"price": int(price.replace(",", "")), "link": link}
                    except:
                        pass
            sorted_items = sorted(items_found.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['price'])
            data = []
            for item in sorted_items:
                print(item[0])
                print(f"${item[1]['price']}")
                print(item[1]['link'])
                print("-------------------------------")
                data.append([item[0], item[1]['price'], item[1]['link']])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data()
```

This code is working on my local machine but not in google colab. Can anyone please give me a solution

### The error I get:

````
<ipython-input-1-4fc0ee293c1c> in <module>()
     90 
     91 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 92     get_data()

<ipython-input-1-4fc0ee293c1c> in get_data()
     25 
     26             # finding the product page
---> 27             page_text = doc.find(class_="list-tool-pagination-text").strong
     28             # finding the number of pages of the products
     29             pages = int(str(page_text).split("/")[-2].split(">")[-1][:-1])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strong'```
````

Comment: Would be easier if you provided us the error you get on Google Collab

Answer (score 0):

The error message is explicit: `doc.find(class_="list-tool-pagination-text")` could not find any element and returned `None`. Why does it return `None`? I cannot guess, but you should log the content of the page that you are trying to parse *somewhere* and control that. I would assume that it is not what you expect.

Comment: Since it works locally, I'm gonna bet that the problem lies with `requests.get(url)`; most likely some refused connection due to firewall.

Comment: But it is working in my local machine and I am sure it will work in yours also but it is not working in Google colab